# implementing custom load balancing in proxiless java grpc client - server communication

Tags: load-balancing, grpc-java

I am trying to understand how to implement custom load balancing in proxiless java grpc client - server communication (with gcp traffic director) that is based on roundtrip latency to an endpoint (subchannel), something that is measurable from the client side. trying my luck here and see if someone implemented something similar.
I am using the latest version of grpc-core 1.54.1

I tried to look at the provided example of custom load balancer based on metrics from the server (ORCA), and also tried to look at the round robin load balancer, but lost my way there

Comment: Did you see the new user guide to custom LBs? https://grpc.io/docs/guides/custom-load-balancing

It is high level as custom LBs is an advanced topic and every implementation is very, well, custom.

Also, I'll mention that since v1.54.0 grpc-java supports weighted round robin load balancing that provides some more sophisticated LB capabilities. Might not be what you need but maybe worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

[WeightedRoundRobinLbPolicy](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/xds/src/main/java/io/grpc/xds/WeightedRoundRobinLoadBalancer.java) is an example that uses load report from the backends to do load balancing. In the implementation you can see it uses ORCA API to get the load report call back in LB.

For the server side, you also need to use ORCA API to set up the server to send the load report. And you have to choose ORCA per-rpc or out-of-band.

In order to plug in your own LB policy to xds, you need to config at the traffic director and maybe other setups: https://cloud.google.com/traffic-director/docs/proxyless-configure-advanced-traffic-management#custom-lb-config